# Real vs Actual memory in Xymon/Hobbit

Tags: linux, memory, monitoring

What is the difference between real and actual memory usage in xymon ?

Comment: According to Henrik Stoerner at http://lists.xymon.com/oldarchive/2006/02/msg00115.html , **real** is the physical memory, **actual** is the amount of memory in use not including buffers and cache, all based on the output of the `free` command.

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you add your comment as an answer, it can help others :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Henrik Stoerner at http://lists.xymon.com/oldarchive/2006/02/msg00115.html , **real** is the physical memory, **actual** is the amount of memory in use not including buffers and cache, all based on the output of the `free` command.